# IOS app not asking for permission on IOS 14

Tags: ios, flutter

Recently, I had my app rejected on the review of App Store connect because it was not requesting the user's permission to access the camera. I found that, testing in different devices, it is requesting the permission on IOS 12, however on IOS 14 it is not, the dialog won't show up and it opens the camera directly. I tried to implement `permission_handler` to make it work but nothing. By printing the `Permission.camera.status` I noticed that on IOS 14 is gives me `granted`, as on  IOS 12 it shows `denied`. Do you guys have any idea how to deal with this situation?

I have already added the files to my `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Precisamos de acesso a câmera para tirar fotos.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Precisamos de acesso ao microfone para gravar aúdio.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Precisamos de acesso a galeria para buscar a imagens</string>
```

and the permissions on `Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
     # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
     # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
     #'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
     'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
    'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
    # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
     'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

    ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]

     #'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
    # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
    # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
     #'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0',   

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
     #'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
     #'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
    # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=0'
  ]
  end
 end
end
```

My implementation when I open the camera:

```
 handleTakePhoto() async {
var status = await Permission.camera.status;
print(status);
if (status.isGranted) {
  final PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 675, maxWidth: 960);
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    editImage(pickedFile.path);
  }
} else if (status.isDenied) {
  final PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 675, maxWidth: 960);
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    editImage(pickedFile.path);
  }
} else {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text('Camera Permission'),
            content: Text(
                'This app needs camera access to take pictures for upload user profile photo'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: Text('Deny'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: Text('Settings'),
                onPressed: () => openAppSettings(),
              ),
            ],
          ));
   }
}
```

Comment: If your app is able to access the camera without requesting and receiving permission then you should probably report this to Apple's security bug bounty and make some $ - It should not be possible.  Delete your app from your device and run it; You should be prompted for camera access.  You can check the approval setting in your apps settings

Comment: I uninstalled and installed again several times. Either Debug, release or test flight version. On the IOS 12 it asks for permission whereas on the IOS 14 opens directly.

Comment: Your code is strange.  Why are you showing your own dialog?  The permission handler package calls the native permission request function which will trigger iOS to ask the user for camera permission.  You cannot access the camera without first gaining permission.  Is it possible that Apple's rejection was that your app doesn't use a standard dialog?

Comment: @Paulw11 actually I follow this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646085/how-to-request-and-check-permissions-in-flutter the strange is that even if I use ```Permission.camera.request()``` it doesn't request, because the app starts with the permission granted. The build that I uploaded to Apple didn't have the permission handler because as it is working on IOS 12, I didn't notice it was not working on IOS 14, that is why they rejected.

Comment: Attempting to access the camera without the permission will result in an app crash.  I am sure that your app already having permission is something happening on your device. Can you try a different device?  There is nothing you can do in your app that results in it having camera permission without the user providing it

Comment: @Paulw11 Checking the app settings on both devices after just downloading it from test flight and not opening the app I noticed that the iOS 14 has both permissions granted, for camera and photos, and on IOS 12 it doesn't show as it was not granted yet. I don't think the reason is my device because the App Store reviewer probably had the permissions granted when reviewing too. Do you happen to have a IOS to test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238752/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ricardo-oscar-kanitz).